# How can I convert CameraImageStream CameraImage to jpeg or bitmap in Flutter using Flutter's image-processing libraries?

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing, type-conversion

I cant convert CameraImage from bgra8888 to an jpeg.
I have found different approaches but none of them work.

The last what I tried is:

```
void testB(CameraImage i) async {

    cameraRepository.stopRecording();

    print(i.format.group);

    imglib.Image im = imglib.Image.fromBytes(
      width: (i.planes[0].bytesPerRow / 4).round(),
      height: i.height,
      bytes: (i.planes[0].bytes).buffer);

    imglib.PngEncoder pngEncoder = new imglib.PngEncoder();

    Uint8List png = pngEncoder.encode(im);

    //Uint8List jpeg = imglib.encodeJpg(im);

    imageList.add(png);
```

When I display it in a widget like this:

```
return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Test'),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 1,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return SizedBox(width:500, height:500, child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.cover, image: MemoryImage(BlocProvider.of<CameraBloc>(context).imageList[0], scale: 0.5)),
        )
            ));
          }),
        );
```

I images shows up, but something is wrong with the conversion:

https://pasteboard.co/5yMYpLFxsPkR.jpg

(Thats my Keyboard, so the image isnt complete Noise).

I've tried this code:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imglib;
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

Future<List<int>> convertImagetoPng(CameraImage image) async {
  try {
    imglib.Image img;
    if (image.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.yuv420) {
      img = _convertYUV420(image);
    } else if (image.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888) {
      img = _convertBGRA8888(image);
    }

    imglib.PngEncoder pngEncoder = new imglib.PngEncoder();

    // Convert to png
    List<int> png = pngEncoder.encodeImage(img);
    return png;
  } catch (e) {
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR:" + e.toString());
  }
  return null;
}

// CameraImage BGRA8888 -> PNG
// Color
imglib.Image _convertBGRA8888(CameraImage image) {
  return imglib.Image.fromBytes(
    image.width,
    image.height,
    image.planes[0].bytes,
    format: imglib.Format.bgra,
  );
}

// CameraImage YUV420_888 -> PNG -> Image (compresion:0, filter: none)
// Black
imglib.Image _convertYUV420(CameraImage image) {
  var img = imglib.Image(image.width, image.height); // Create Image buffer

  Plane plane = image.planes[0];
  const int shift = (0xFF << 24);

  // Fill image buffer with plane[0] from YUV420_888
  for (int x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
    for (int planeOffset = 0;
        planeOffset < image.height * image.width;
        planeOffset += image.width) {
      final pixelColor = plane.bytes[planeOffset + x];
      // color: 0x FF  FF  FF  FF
      //           A   B   G   R
      // Calculate pixel color
      var newVal = shift | (pixelColor << 16) | (pixelColor << 8) | pixelColor;

      img.data[planeOffset + x] = newVal;
    }
  }

  return img;
}
```

But it seems outdated. Got different errors when i tried it.

**UPDATE**

```
imglib.Image im = imglib.Image.fromBytes(
  width: (i.planes[0].bytesPerRow / 4).round(),
  height: i.height,
  bytes: (i.planes[0].bytes).buffer);
```

After changing height to width and width to height, the image is no clearer and almost good. I confused this as it seems.

But its still not good.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is struggling to convert this Streaming CameraImage on IPhone (brga8888),
since a new Version of Image Package the Parameter have changed:

```
imglib.Image im = imglib.Image.fromBytes(
      height: i.height,
      width: i.width,
      bytes: (i.planes[0].bytes).buffer,
      format: imglib.Format.uint8,
      order: ChannelOrder.bgra
    );
```

This produced a clean Image.